# Ubuntu Server 18.04: fstab entry for root partition has passno = 0

Tags: server, ssd, fstab, fsck

The fstab entry for the root partition on my SSD is:

`UUID=fd3b80aa-901c-11e8-a5c4-e0d55e5a7608 / ext4 defaults 0 0`

This was generated automatically during the Ubuntu Server installation. Note that `passno` (the final value) is set to 0. Everything I've read says that for the root partition this value should be set to 1. Is this something special for an SSD or is it a mistake that I need to correct?

Comment: My NVMe SSD contains: `UUID=f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`. If you do change yours to `1` you must also replace `defaults` with `errors=remount-ro`. The `1` simply tells the system to run `fsck` (file system check) I believe.

Comment: Your settings are what I would have expected. I wanted to check if this was deliberate for some reason I didn't understand, or a mistake/bug in the server install. It looks like the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is this is due to [bug #1785354](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1785354): "/etc/fstab: fs_passno is 0 for all file systems". So yes, you should probably correct it.